# Convert standard format date string to datetime object

Tags: python, sorting, date

I have a list of tuples, each containing a date, and then a number.

```
days = [('04/02/15', 4.5),('03/15/15', 5.0),('04/21/15', 1.9)]
```

I want to sort them by date. 
How do I go about converting them into DateTime objects or otherwise sorting them?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183793/str-to-time-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime):

```
from time import strptime
days = [('04/02/15', 4.5), ('03/15/15', 5.0), ('04/21/15', 1.9)]
days.sort(key = lambda tup: strptime(tup[0], '%m/%d/%y'))
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed to do. I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @MikeVaughan: `time.strptime()` returns `time.struct_time`, not `datetime` object as `datetime.strptime()` does and the question title indicates. Though, as a sorting key, `time.struct_time` works  here as well.