# Converting 24 hour time to 12 hour time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the list of times posted below and am having difficulties with converting it to the following:

**Step 1**: Convert to EST time in 24-hour format.

**Step 2**: Convert to 12 hour EST time format.

I have tried doing this in both Python and Pandas and I'm willing to use whatever is easiest.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
['00:05', '17:07', '23:05', '23:05', '23:10', '23:10', '00:10', '00:15', 
'00:40', '01:40', '02:10']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [0-23 hour military clock to standard time (hh:mm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691007/0-23-hour-military-clock-to-standard-time-hhmm)

Comment: Those are helpful, but I haven't seen any posts where there is a list of times involved.  All I have seen are manually inputted time scenarios and I would ideally like to loop through the list (if doable).

Comment: what is the exact output format you'd like? should it include am/pm?

Comment: ideally yes, please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can easily achieve what you're looking for with `datetime`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> times = [ "08:00", "23:00" ]
>>> [datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M").strftime("%I:%M %p") for time in times]
['08:00 AM', '11:00 PM']
```

This reads your `time` in with `strptime` and then outputs it with `strftime` inside a list comprehension. To convert this to `EST` with no daylight savings time (which is `-05:00`) you can use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

```
>>> import pytz
>>> [datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M").replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('EST')).strftime("%I:%M %p") for time in times]
['03:00 AM', '06:00 PM']
```

Which first marks the time as `utc` (`replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)`) and then converts it to EST `astimezone(pytz.timezone('EST'))` before reformatting it to 12 hour time.

Going one step further to what I think you want, which is to get the time today in `EDT` (`EST` factoring in `datetime`) we can take a hint from [this question][2]:

```
converted = []
tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
for time in times:
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M").time()
    converted.append(datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc).replace(hour=time.hour, minute=time.minute).astimezone(tz).strftime("%I:%M %p"))
```

Which will build what I believe you are looking for:

```
['04:00 AM', '07:00 PM']
```

Comment: Beautiful thank you, how would I go about getting this to EST time though?  The list was originally in GMT time

Comment: So because EST may be in daylight savings time or not based on time of year, you need more info to be able to answer this.

Comment: see this thread (including my answer) for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084316/str-to-time-object-in-python-3/51084990#51084990

Comment: If we could somehow subtract 4 hours from each of these that is what I am looking for, sorry really new to this. I was able to accomplish this with timedelta in Pandas but not sure how this would look in just Python

Comment: i can provide that pretty easily. let me get you an update.

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks like it is behind 1 hour but maybe that is my fault giving you bad information.  Either way thank you for all of your help on this! I've been spending most of the day on here looking for solutions and have been struggling.

Comment: @CamGi i have provided conversion to EST, but EST is `-05:00` not `-04:00` (which is `EDT`).

Comment: @CamGi updated once more to show you how to use today's offset for `EDT`

Comment: Incredible, thank you Matthew! You have salvaged this day of frustration